# How to check for variable, then return error if not valid

Tags: python, if-statement, eval

```
pie="I like pie"
banana="I like bananas"
cake="I like cake"
die=67
running = True

while running:
    item = eval(input("Select your item:  "))

    if item == "die":
        running = False
    elif item !="die":
        print(item)
    else:
        print("Invalid entry. try again")
```

I'm not entirely sure how to get across what I'm asking, but I want the user to be able to enter an input, then search a list of several hundred variables (only a few shown here), then display the variable if it is one. If the user input is not a variable, I want the an error, try again message. Finally, if the user inputs "die", then the program terminates.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: `eval`? WHY?! Looking at this python code makes my eyes hurt. And that's something python code should never cause! :) Use a dict instead of standalone variables!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
output_dict = {
    'pie': "I like pie",
    'banana': "I like bananas",
    'cake': "I like cake"
}

item = None
while item != 'die':
    item = raw_input("Select your item:")
    if item != 'die':
        item = output_dict.get(item, None)
        if item:
            print item
        else:
            print("Invalid entry. try again")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this instead, just use a dict to hold all your variables

```
my_dict = {'pie':'I like pie',
           'banana' : 'I like banana'
          ...
          }

running = True

while running:
   item = raw_input("select item:")
   if item=='die':
       running = False
   elif item in my_dict:
       print my_dict[item]
   else:
       print "try again"
```

Just a comment about your code, eval(input(...)) is not nice since input is eval(raw_input(..)), and you shouldn't be using input in this case (because of the eval) if I understand what you are trying to do, try to use raw_input instead.

Hope it helps!